# Blue screen when rewriting packets at DATAGRAM_DATA layer in WFP

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-firewall, wfp

I've been trying to modify outgoing DNS packets via the `DATAGRAM_DATA` layer in WFP, however i get blue screen errors when rewriting the destination ip in the outgoing packet. What am i doing wrong?

I admit i found the parameters for `FwpsInjectTransportSendAsync` a bit confusing, and was unsure exactly what to put in for the sendParams arg - though i think what i have looks right.

```cpp
RtlIpv4StringToAddressExW(
L"1.1.1.1", // hard-coding the new (rewritten) dns server for now
FALSE,
&sin4.sin_addr,
&sin4.sin_port);

RtlIpv4StringToAddressExW(
    L"8.8.8.8",        // hard-coding the original dns server for now
    FALSE,
    &origSin4.sin_addr,
    &origSin4.sin_port);
```

```cpp
if ((Direction == FWP_DIRECTION_OUTBOUND) && (PacketInjectionState == FWPS_PACKET_NOT_INJECTED) && (RemotePort == 53) && (RemoteAddress == origSin4.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr))
{

    UINT32 IpHeaderSize = inMetaValues->ipHeaderSize;
    UINT32 TransportHeaderSize = inMetaValues->transportHeaderSize;
    UINT64 endpointHandle = inMetaValues->transportEndpointHandle;

    PNET_BUFFER NetBuffer = NET_BUFFER_LIST_FIRST_NB((PNET_BUFFER_LIST)layerData);
    NdisRetreatNetBufferDataStart(NetBuffer, IpHeaderSize + TransportHeaderSize, 0, NULL);

    PNET_BUFFER_LIST NetBufferList = NULL;
    NTSTATUS Status = FwpsAllocateCloneNetBufferList(layerData, NULL, NULL, 0, &NetBufferList);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status))
    {
        return;
    }

    NdisAdvanceNetBufferDataStart(NetBuffer, IpHeaderSize + TransportHeaderSize, FALSE, NULL);

    if (!NetBufferList)
    {
        return;
    }

    NetBuffer = NET_BUFFER_LIST_FIRST_NB(NetBufferList);

    PIPV4_HEADER IpHeader = NdisGetDataBuffer(NetBuffer, sizeof(IPV4_HEADER), NULL, 1, 0);

    // Rewriting the dest ip
    IpHeader->DestinationAddress = sin4.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr;

    // Updating the IP checksum
    UpdateIpv4HeaderChecksum(IpHeader, sizeof(IPV4_HEADER));

    // not 100% sure the sendParams argument is setup correctly, the docs are slightly unclear
    FWPS_TRANSPORT_SEND_PARAMS sendParams = {
        .remoteAddress = (UCHAR*)IpHeader->DestinationAddress,
        .remoteScopeId = inMetaValues->remoteScopeId,
        .controlData = inMetaValues->controlData,
        .controlDataLength = inMetaValues->controlDataLength,
        .headerIncludeHeader = inMetaValues->headerIncludeHeader,
        .headerIncludeHeaderLength = inMetaValues->headerIncludeHeaderLength
    };

    Status = FwpsInjectTransportSendAsync(g_InjectionHandle, NULL, endpointHandle, 0, &sendParams, AF_INET, inMetaValues->compartmentId, NetBufferList, DriverDatagramDataInjectComplete, NULL);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status))
    {
        FwpsFreeCloneNetBufferList(NetBufferList, 0);
    }

    classifyOut->actionType = FWP_ACTION_BLOCK;
    classifyOut->rights &= ~FWPS_RIGHT_ACTION_WRITE;
    classifyOut->flags |= FWPS_CLASSIFY_OUT_FLAG_ABSORB;
}
```

Comment: first what you need todo - look *memory.dmp*. what is bug code, where, call stack. may be you just view instruction in your code which cause bug. may be (say pool(heap) corrupt ) bug in arbitrary context. are bug stable and repeatable (always in same place) or in random place/time. this need in question but not simply *blue screen*

Comment: @RbMm oh it's such simple/small code i thought the issue might be obvious to someone with experirence with WFP.

How do i find and look at the memory.dmp ?

Comment: no, [*Kernel memory dump*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/generate-kernel-or-complete-crash-dump) is always useful and make task much more simply. also - before system restart - dump located inside *pagefile.sys* - if you got crash on virtual machine - you can simply open *pagefile.sys* inside *windbg* after crash and before restart

Answer (score 2):

Two things stand out to me, both in the `sendParams`.

First, `remoteAddress` is incorrect. It needs to a pointer to the address, so it should be `(UCHAR*)&IpHeader->DestinationAddress`.

Second, `FwpsInjectTransportSendAsync()` is asynchronous so any parameters you pass to it need to stay valid until it completes which may be after your calling function returns. Typically you allocate some context structure that contains `sendParams` and deep copies of relevant members (`remoteAddress` and `controlData`). You pass this as the context to the completion routine where you free it.

Comment: Thanks, that's great info. Out of interest, which layers support data flows? I'm trying to associate a flow context in the CONNECT_REDIRECT layer and access it in the DATAGRAM_DATA layer, but i can't seem to get a flow handle in the CONNECT_REDIRECT layer...

Comment: The issue with CONNECT_REDIRECT is that it gets invoked prior to the flow being created. You'll have to associate your context with the flow in AUTH_CONNECT or AUTH_FLOW_ESTABLISHED instead.

Comment: thanks so much! may i ask how you know all this stuff? i can't find this info in the docs at all, do you hvae another resource you can link to?

Comment: A combination of the documentation, sample code, forum posts, and experience. A lot of this stuff is actually in the documentation, but it's either not well organized or not explicit enough.

Comment: No, I'm employed fulltime and only got into working on a WFP driver within the past year or so. I can answer any SO questions if I know the answer.

Comment: I was able to verify that the return of `PIPV4_HEADER IpHeader NdisGetDataBuffer(NetBuffer, sizeof(IPV4_HEADER), NULL, 1, 0);` is NULL -- any idea why that would be the case? I had to modify the amount of the `Retreat` so it's just IpHeaderSize as outbound packets get the transport header

Comment: This is one of those things that's not obvious, and actually obfuscated by the documentation. Here's a [link](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/network/trans/ddproxy/sys/DD_proxy.c#L650) to a comment in the sample code that describes what's happening.

Comment: The thing you have to keep in mind is that the network stack is a **stack**. On the inbound path, packets come in through IP layer then Transport layer then Data layer. On the outbound path, packets go out through Data  layer then Transport Layer then IP layer. So on the inbound path, next layers can see data from previous layers. But on the outbound path, previous layers can not see data from next layers because it hasn't been constructed yet.

Comment: So if you want to access the IP header of an outbound UDP datagram then you'd have to do that at the OUTBOUND_IPPACKET layer. Though if your intention is just to override the IP header then the `FwpsInjectTransportSendAsync()` will construct the IP header for you.

Comment: sah interesting! so if i want to change the dest/source addresses in the ip header, i CAN do thta at the DATAGRAM_DATA_LAYER ? and then use FwpsInjectNetwork (not InjectTransport) to inject it? or you're saying if i want to modify the dest/source addresses of an ip header i have to do that at the OUTBOUND_IPPACKET layer?

Comment: I think you can do it at DATAGRAM_DATA but I'm not sure as I've never done it myself. If it is possible I think you'd have to manually insert the UDP header into the buffer, then pass the buffer to `FwpsConstructIpHeaderForTransportPacket()` to build the IP header (or manually build it), then inject it with `FwpsInjectNetworkSendAsync()`.

Comment: jesus lol, i was thinking that WFP was a nicer API than macos kernel extensions, but i take it all back! macos kext network/socket API is way nicer than this! thanks for the info though! :)